# VS project template: Set solution & project name based on input in wizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, project-template

Is it somehow possible to have the solution & project name and folder be defined based on the input in the wizard of a Visual Studio 2013 (single) project template?

My use case is that we have guidelines how to name solutions, and I would like to have wizard in the project template which asks for the customer name and based on that the solution should be accordingly named. This would make the "Name" and "Solution name" entry in the "New project" dialog obsolete. Ideally I would be able to hide these files, and only show the location selection in the "New project" dialog.